# make random numbers for each row and column

Tags: sql-server, random

I will edit some fake data in my database. But if I will make random numbers for each row and column, it is not so random as I want it. The result can you see on image below.

[image: No random numbers]

Here is my code I use:

```
WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT mintwee, mineen, nul, pluseen, plustwee 
    FROM Topic
)
SELECT mintwee = CAST(RAND()*100 AS INT),
       mineen = CAST(RAND()*100 AS INT), 
       nul = CAST(RAND()*100 AS INT),
       pluseen = CAST(RAND()*100 AS INT),
       plustwee = CAST(RAND()*100 AS INT)
FROM x
```

and this:

```
WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT 
        mintwee = CAST(RAND()*100 AS INT), 
        mineen = CAST(RAND()*100 AS INT),
        nul = CAST(RAND()*100 AS INT), 
        pluseen = CAST(RAND()*100 AS INT), 
        plustwee = CAST(RAND()*100 AS INT)
    FROM Topic
)
SELECT mintwee, mineen, nul, pluseen, plustwee
FROM x ;
```

But both has the same result. I know, I must use an `UPDATE` statement, but this is only for try if the result is good. After it, I am going to use the `UPDATE` statement.

I use SQL server with an express 2014 version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is no correlation between the table rows and the `RAND` function, the expression is evaluated only once in the query.

One method to generated random values is with the `NEWID()` function.  The example below generates random integer values between 0-99 range.  The modulo value can be adjusted for a different range and you can use this basic technique to generate random values for dates, character, etc.

```
WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT mintwee, mineen, nul, pluseen, plustwee 
  FROM Topic
)
SELECT mintwee = CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(16)),1, 3) AS int) % 100,
       mineen = CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(16)),1, 3) AS int) % 100,
       nul = CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(16)),1, 3) AS int) % 100,
       pluseen = CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(16)),1, 3) AS int) % 100,
       plustwee= CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(16)),1, 3) AS int) % 100
FROM x;
```

The expression can be simplified if you need only 32-bit integers.  Additional examples:

```
--positive int
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()));
--positive and negative int
SELECT CHECKSUM(NEWID());
--positive bigint
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(16)),1, 7) AS bigint);
--negative and positive bigint
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(16)),1, 8) AS bigint);
--dates between now and 1 year ago
SELECT DATEADD(day, -ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 365, GETDATE());
--random uppercase character
SELECT CAST(CAST(65 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 26) AS binary(1)) AS char(1));
```

Comment: `NEWID()` was never meant to be a random number generator, so it is not clear what distribution you'll get for random numbers generated this way. Since SQL Server 2008 there is [`CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx) that may be easier to use (you can specify the length of the generated number in bytes) and which produces "better" (cryptographically) random numbers.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, I completely agree `NEWID` isn't adequate for cryptography but that is not the use case here.  `CRYPT_GEM_RANDOM` is a good idea to use here though, since it eliminates the `SUBSTRING` ugliness.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Rand1.n as RandomIntegerBetweenAB
     , Rand2.n as RandomIntegerBetweenXY
     , DateAdd(Day, Rand2.n, GetDate()) as RandomDateAddBetweenXY
     , Rand3.n as RandomInteger
from api.RandomIntBetween(0, 100) as Rand1
cross apply api.RandomIntBetween(-365, 365) as Rand2
cross apply api.RandomIntBetween(default, default) as Rand3;
```

We use this view to generate a random integer (only because SQL Server won't simply let us use `Crypt_Gen_Random()` in a UDF):

```
create view api.vw_RandomInt
with schemabinding
as (
    select Cast(Crypt_Gen_Random(4) as int) as n
);
```

Using this view as a base we can get whatever random integer and then do some maths to rescale it:

```
create function api.RandomIntBetween (
    @x int = -2147483648
  , @y int = 2147483647
)
returns table
with schemabinding as
return (
    select Cast(Round(c.f, 0, 0) as int) as n
    from (values(
        case when @x < @y then @x else @y end
      , case when @y > @x then @y else @x end
    )) a ([Min], [Max])
    cross join api.vw_RandomInt as b
    cross apply api.NormalizeBetween(
        b.n
      , -2147483648
      , 2147483647
      , a.[Min] - 0.5
      , a.[Max] + 0.5
    ) as c
);
```

Where the definition of NormalizeBetween is:

```
create function api.NormalizeBetween (
    @f float = 1.
  , @x float = 0.
  , @y float = 1.
  , @a float = 0.
  , @b float = 1.
)
returns table
with schemabinding as
return (
    select ((@f - @x) * (@b - @a)) / NullIf(@y - @x, 0) + @a as f
);
```