# Generate fake data for several tables with relationships

Tags: sql-server, insert, random, relations

I have 3 tables where I want to generate fake data in `UsersCategoryLink`.

How can I insert in the table `UserCategoryLink` the column `UserID` with random users from the table `User` and a random id from the table `Categories`. In this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bafda/2) you can see the tables with some values.

- `UsersCategoryLink` must be filled with random users and categories.
- Every user must have two categories.
- `UserID` and `CategoryID` are primary keys, so every value must be unique.
- I am using SQL Server Express.

[image: Tables and relations with some information what I want]

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119068/make-random-numbers-for-each-row-and-column

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my version of the cross-reference table where you'll store users and the categories they are members of.  Notice there is a primary key clustered index on `(UserID, CategoryID)`; this ensures each row is unique:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.XREFUserCategories
(
    UserID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_XREFUserCategories_UserID
        FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES dbo.Users(UserID)
    , CategoryID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_XREFUserCategories_CategoryID
        FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES dbo.Categories(CategoryID)
    , CONSTRAINT PK_XREFUserCategories
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserID, CategoryID)
);
GO
```

Since you already have data in the `Users` and `Categories` tables, you can use a CTE with the `ROW_NUMBER` windowing function partitioned by `UserID` and *ordered by* an essentially random value, `NEWID()`.  This allows us to pick precisely two "categories" for each "user":

```
;WITH rs AS 
(
    SELECT u.UserID
        , c.CategoryID
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY u.UserID 
            ORDER BY NEWID()
    )
    FROM dbo.Users u
        , dbo.Categories c
)
INSERT INTO dbo.XREFUserCategories(UserID, CategoryID)
SELECT rs.UserID
    , rs.CategoryID
FROM rs
WHERE rs.rn <= 2;
```

The following is a sample of rows I generated on my system:

[image]